# Refresh page after tab change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 tabs that only change the order of my posts. The tabs content is changing with javascript without refreshing the page, but now I need to refresh it, because i'm making a post with ajax and I need to update that post in the other tab.

my html tab code:

```
<div id="tabs-container" >
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active test" id="recent" title="Order recommendations by Votes"><a href="#tab-1" >Votes</a></li>
    <li class="test" id="votes" title="Order recommendations by Recent"><a href="#tab-2">Recent</a></li>
    <li class="test" id="oldest" title="Order recommendations by Oldest"><a href="#tab-3">Oldest</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
    <p><%= render partial: 'improvement_actions/improvement_action', collection: @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order(cached_votes_score: :desc), locals: { tab: "votes" } %></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    <p><%= render partial: 'improvement_actions/improvement_action', collection: @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order("created_at DESC"), :locals => { tab: "recent" } %></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    <p><%= render partial: 'improvement_actions/improvement_action', collection: @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order("created_at ASC") , :locals => { tab: "oldest" } %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();

    });

});
```

I tried:

```
var url = window.location;
window.location = url;
```

or :

```
location.reload();
```

but its not working well because It appears the posts and then refreshes the page, and its to slow also

Comment: if you reload the page youre just going to reset all your data including your ajax data.

Comment: no, my ajax data its posting on the database

Comment: Youre saving data to the database via ajax and once thats complete you want to reload the page so that the new data is used?

Comment: why not re-render the partial via ajax once your data is saved

Comment: im inserting a post in the db, and I have 3 tabs (order by votes, recent, oldest), my problem is that if I change the tab, the post will be at the end of the list, its not assuming the order

Comment: is it possible to call `<%= render partial: 'improvement_actions/improvement_action', collection: @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order(cached_votes_score: :desc), locals: { tab: "votes" } %>` everytime I change the tab?